# Cannot hide cities behind spinning globe

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have put together a jsfiddle where I implement a Bostock spinning globe.

I then try to plot a couple of markers (cities). This is only partly successful. For some reason not all are plotted -and, I assume for a similar reason- the script that is meant to hide those invisible cities (i.e. behind the globe)is not working as it should. The markers are still dancing around uninvitedly when you scroll them out of sight.

I have put together the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/jg3axLmx/1/

The below is the script that is meant to 'hide' the markers behind the globe:

```
function position_cities() {
   var centerPos = projection.invert([380,380]);
   var arc = d3.geo.greatArc();
   svg.selectAll(".cities")
     .style("fill", "blue")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
       return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
       return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
     })
     .style({
       "color": "#FFF",
       "display": function(d) { 
         var x = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
         var y = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
         var d = arc.distance({
           source: [d.lat, d.lon],
           target: centerPos
         });
         return (d > 1.57) ? 'none' : 'inline';
       }
     });
 }
```

Additionally - would you know how to add labels to these markers, and make them square instead of circular?

The question above is similar to this:
[Cannot hide labels 'behind' spinning D3 Globe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064044/cannot-hide-labels-behind-spinning-d3-globe/41070453?noredirect=1#comment69394125_41070453)

Here you can see a marker in Brazil that is still visible
[image: Here you can see a marker in Brazil that is still visible]

Comment: There are 4 cities marked & all those 4 markers are visible to me on the globe. Also what do you mean by "invisible cities" ?

Comment: The ones that should be hidden as on the other side of the globe.

Comment: Then its actually hidden for me. I can see a proper opaque globe(not a transparent one). Sounds more like a local browser issue. Which browser are you using. Specs?

Comment: Chrome. Move the globe around a bit and you shall be able to replicate it easily

Comment: Hmm you mean the "markers" behind are visible(not actually the cities) .. right ?

Comment: Yes. The markers and the cities are the same thing :)

Comment: Not really .. to you may be, since you know the issue you know what you are talking about. But for people reading it for the first time, first thing that comes to their mind is actual "cities"(not markers OF the cities), meaning the area map of the city.

Comment: What is about "I then try to plot a couple of markers (cities)" you do not understand?

Comment: Where does `380` come from in this `centerPos = projection.invert([380,380]);`?   I imagine you started off of [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4686432), he calculates off of width and height....

Comment: I have tried to set these values to 400 but the issue still arises... :(

Comment: @Noobster You are doing it the hard way by drawing regular circles—you'd be better off with using GeoJSON Point objects instead. Have a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35189859/4235784) to a similar problem in [*"D3 geo: getting projection.clipAngle to work on all specified elements"*](/q/35180597).

Comment: Hello -thank you so much for your recommendation. Your b.lock is no longer running but I have tried to help myself to your script and implemented it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/a8y2onsn/). The pins have been dropped on the globe in the right place but they do not seem to be updating with events.

Comment: @Noobster With the release of v2 of his TopoJSON library Mike Bostock removed the examples from the repository, which invalidated the link to the `world-110m.json` file. I corrected my Block, which is now again up and running. Since many 3rd-party examples directly refer to this file for loading the data, I suspect we are going to see a lot of examples which stopped working because of broken links. We should keep this in mind for the near future ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it,

as noted in the comments, the center point is at 400,400:

```
var centerPos = projection.invert([400,400]);
```

and you have mixed up the order latitude and longitude in the source coordinate here:

```
var d = arc.distance({source: [d.lat, d.lon], target: centerPos});
  return (d > 1.57) ? 'none' : 'inline';
```

This should read:

```
var d = arc.distance({source: [d.lon, d.lat], target: centerPos});
  return (d > 1.57) ? 'none' : 'inline';
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L51y3c1b/

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the sub-question:

> Additionally - would you know how to add labels to these markers, and make them square instead of circular?

Line 72, instead of doing this:

```
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
           })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
           })
```

append a "g" element instead:

```
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
           return "translate("+ 
                    projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0] +
                    "," +
                    projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]+
                    ")";
           })
```

Then

```
     cities.append("circle") 
           .attr("cx", 0)
           .attr("cy", 0)
```

and

```
    cities.append("text").text("New York");
```

You can fiddle with the x and y coordinates of the text. Also, everytime you used to change the cx and cy attribute of a city, you need to change the "transform" attribute of the g element instead (as I've shown above).

As for your main question, the best clue I can give is that `d3.geo.greatArc();` is deprecated, so maybe you should look for a new method for computing arc distance on the globe.

Answer (score 1):

In the js fiddle you provide you are setting the cities once but never calling them again. In your `startAnimation` method the same way you are updating the labels the cities display must be updated too. If not the display will depend on the first load.

As for the shape change you are defining it when you create them in here:

```
var cities = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data([
            {"code":"RIO","city":"RIO DE JANEIRO","country":"BRAZIL","lat":-22.90,"lon":-43.24},
            {"code":"BSB","city":"BRASILIA","country":"BRAZIL","lat":-15.67,"lon":-47.43},
            {"code":"ZNZ","city":"ZANZIBAR","country":"TANZANIA","lat":-6.13,"lon":39.31},
            {"code":"TYO","city":"TOKYO","country":"JAPAN","lat":35.68,"lon":139.76}
            ])
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
               })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
               })
            .attr("r", 3)
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "cities")
            .attr("id", function(d){ return d.code})
```

Those attributes such as cx, cy are related to an SVG circle shape along with the circle tag specified. To create new shapes you will need to change here to the tag and attributes relative to the shape you want.

Comment: Hello Fabio -thanks for this. Shape attribute comments taken on board and I now understand what was going wrong. Regarding the `position_cities()` function I do call it in the `refresh()` function so would expect the function to be called whenever the mouse moves or there is any kind of event? I have however called the script where you suggested ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/jg3axLmx/3/)) but this has not fixed the issue

Comment: Hi Noobster,  glad to help and my bad to not have spotted that call! :D